# calculating max payout. Casino Probability. pls help

Tags: probability

On a slot mashine there are 4 rolls. each roll has 4 colors. Yellow, Blue, Green, Purple. on each role there are 15 fields where the 4 colors can appear.

Chance for 4 Yellow: 6/15 * 6/15 * 6/15 * 6/15 = 0.0256

Chance for 4 Blue:   4/15 * 4/15 * 4/15 * 4/15 = 0.00505679

Chance for 4 Green: 3/15 * 3/15 * 3/15 * 3/15 = 0.0016

Chance for 4 Purple: 2/15 * 2/15 * 2/15 * 2/15 = 0.00031604938

The cost for 3 spins is 1$.

What should the maximum payout be for each of the colors in order not to generate loss?

Help with how to solve this would be greatly appriciated!!!

Comment: Under what conditions does the house pay off?

Comment: house pays different amounts depending on the rarety. in order it goes, yellow, blue, green, purple. you need to get 4 in a row of 1 specific color. which i already calculated the chance of that happening.